# C++11 metaprogramming - lookup enum value during compilation (values contains gaps)

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, metaprogramming

Is there a way, **at compile-time**, to verify that a given
value is within the values of a given enum, thus valid?

```
enum myenum { val1 = 10, val2 = 30, val3 = 45 }

template <myenum t>
class myClass
{ ... }

myClass<10> a; // fails, OK
myClass<val1> b; // compiles OK
myClass<myenum(24)> c; //compiles, NOT OK!
```

Using a second template non-type boolean parameter would be useful in there, and the value of that boolean would be given by a meta-function, that given a value would verify that the value is within the values of myenum.

I looked through various enum related question, like how to iterate an enum, and it seems it can't be done.

Comment: With a `C`-style cast, I don't think you can prohibit this.

Comment: `myenum(24)` is still a valid value of that type. You might not want to handle such a value, but it's still valid. In C and C++ enumeration types are not restricted to the values that correspond to enumerators, that's by design and is a good thing.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think it isn't a good thing to *not have the other option*.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: It is valid the same way as `void* ptr = (void*)1;`. No one sane can expect good thing from it. If creator of the enum considered 24 valid input, he would add it into the enum definition.

Comment: @mity **Utter nonsense!** What about bitmask types e.g. `std::ios::openmode` might be an enum, are you suggesting `std::ios::in|std::ios::out` is not "valid" because there's no `inout` enumerator with the same value as `in|out`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, you can declare custom class types that behave that way (and add iteration over the values and conversion to strings etc.) but an enum is not such a type, it's a simple built-in integral type.

Comment: `val1` and so on are called the *enumerators*, not the values of an enumeration type. The valid values of `myenum` are those of its underlying type (which is some integral type) which can be found via `std::underlying_type<myenum>::type`. In any case here you will have more valid values than there are enumerators.

Comment: @Jonathan You can also declare custom class types that behave like bitfields.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: No. Compile this: 
`enum E {
    VAL1 = 0x01,
    VAL2 = 0x02
};

static E e1 = VAL1;
static E e2 = VAL2;
static E e3 = VAL1 | VAL2;`

On the last statement you get error.

Comment: @mity see 17.5.2.1.3 Bitmask types [bitmask.types]. Let's move this to chat if you want to understand exactly why you're wrong ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely: Bitmask is implemented using an enum + overloaded operators. The latter is missing in the question here, working around it via cast is misuse.

Comment: @mity : And how do you think those overloaded operators work internally if not with casts?

Comment: @ildjarn: I argue that by implementing the operators the author of the enum says: "Using bitwise or is legal and the API taking the enum eats combinations of the values as well".

Comment: @mity : The C++ standard says that's true of _all_ enums.

Comment: @mity, so adding `operator|` suddenly makes an invalid value into a valid one? This goes back to what I said earlier "You might not want to handle such a value, but it's still valid." The C++ standard is not defined by what you (or the OP) would like to be true to fit your idea of how things should work.

Comment: @ildjarn: Source a.cc: `enum E { VAL1 = 0x01, VAL2 = 0x02 }; static E e3 = VAL1 | VAL2;` Command `g++ --std=c++11 -c a.cc` results in `error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'E'` (gcc version 4.7). To "fix" I should implement the operator. I should do that only if I also make all interfaces taking `E` as parameter also values resulting from using the operator, to keep it consistent.

Comment: @mity : I really don't know what you're trying to prove. The bottom line is that the standard says that `E e3 = static_cast<E>(VAL1 | VAL2);` always has well-defined behavior; whether or not you hide the cast behind some other overloaded operator is irrelevant.

Comment: @ildjarn: I'm not trying to prove anything. All the time, I'm just noting that morally, the enum is just set of discrete values listed in it and the set can **optionally** be extended by defining some operators. But if it is not, the author probably tells by it, that the API will not accept values resulted from using arbitrarily chosen operator as a legal input. And if an user of the API does so anyway, he is shooting his own leg. Nothing more.

Comment: @mity : That being the case, you seem to just be rephrasing what's in your answer, which I've already upvoted. :-]

Comment: "_the enum is just set of discrete values listed in it and the set can optionally be extended by defining some operators_" that's not what the C++ standard says, it's just your personal, and incorrect, interpretation. Luc Danton has it correct in his comment above.

Answer (score 5):

```
enum myenum { val1 = 10, val2 = 30, val3 = 45 };
template<myenum e> struct is_valid_myenum { static const bool value = (e==val1 || e==val2 || e==val3); };

template<myenum t>
class myClass
{
    static_assert(is_valid_myenum<t>::value, "t must be a valid enum value");
};

myClass<10> a; // fails, OK
myClass<val1> b; // compiles OK
myClass<myenum(24)> c; // fails, OK
```

---

If you really, really want to avoid the duplication (and aren't interested in using some external tool to generate sourcecode) you can resort to macro hackery.

```
#define LIST \
    ITEM(val1,10)\
    ITEM(val2,30)\
    ITEM(val3,45)

#define ITEM(NAME,VALUE) NAME = VALUE,

enum myenum { LIST };

#undef ITEM

#define ITEM(NAME,VALUE) e==NAME ||

template<myenum e> struct is_valid_myenum { static const bool value = ( LIST false ); };

template<myenum t>
class myClass
{
    static_assert(is_valid_myenum<t>::value, "t must be a valid enum value");
};

myClass<10> a; // fails, OK
myClass<val1> b; // compiles OK
myClass<myenum(24)> c; // fails, OK
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Thanks! Still though doesn't answer my question. The problem with this solution is that if I change the enum values (either add or delete values) I have to make sure is_valid_myenum is updated, and its error-prone. That's why I wanted a way to iterate through the enumeration value.

Answer (score 2):

You can never prevent other developers to shoot in their own foot. You can never win. Just ensure your API does not make it **easy**.

If he takes an invalid value, casts it, and then passes it to you, it is purely his problem. This is the same kind of problem as if you provide him a function taking a pointer of type `T*` as parameter, but he takes some random data (of arbitrary type), casts it to `T*` and passes it in.

That's how casting works: The person who does the cast is responsible to guarantee that the casted expression can be safely interpreted as value of the type he casts to.

Comment: Well, technically in this case I can, and if I can make it very hard to misuse I'd rather to. That's achievable either with template specialization or explicit template instatiation. But in both case, if I change the enumerator I have to make sure the specialization or the explicit instatiation is in sync and I don't like that.

Comment: @emitrax: You will remove one bullet from many, potentially adding other ones by typing a lot of unnecessary code so other peeople still can shoot their foot. And probably make it less readable. I don't consider it good trade-off, but your choice.

Comment: To quote like every major C++ FAQ out there:  "Do NOT try to prevent espionage.  You will fail."

Answer (score 0):

Short of redeclaring all your information in metaprogramming form, it cannot be done. However, you could for instance do:

```
enum myenum { val1 = 10, val2 = 30, val3 = 45 };
typedef vector_c< myenum, val1, val2, val3 > typed_myenum;

typedef
    contains< typed_myenum, integral_c< myenum, val >::value
    val_found;
```

Using functionality from **Boost.MPL**, although the actual syntax might be a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to check that a value is within a valid range of an enum at run time, less at compile time.

The only way to check is to brute force check for every value. Something like this:

```
enum lala
{
  A = 10,
  B = 20,
  C = 30
};

template< int value >
struct T
{
  static_assert( (value == A) || (value == B ) || (value == C), "wrong value" );
};

int main()
{
  T< 10 > t10;
  T< 20 > t20;
  T< 25 > t25;
  T< 30 > t30;

  (void)t10;(void)t20;(void)t25;(void)t30;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the enum's name is not important for you, maybe you can just transfer it to an array, such as:

```
const int myenum[]={10,30,45}
```

then use an index to reference them from the myenum.

```
template<unsigned int t>
class myClass
{
    static_assert(t < sizeof(myenum)/sizeof(int), "t must be a valid enum index");
    int val=myenum[t];
    ...
};
```